# Atom Indent Issue

Tags: atom-editor, auto-indent

I have a python tensorflow script that used 2 space indent. My Atom preferences have tab set to `default: 2`. When I hit enter after a : Atom does a 4 space auto-indent, inconsistent with the rest of the file and with the preferences.

In fact, a fresh install comes with the default set like this:

[image: Atom Tab default]

However, if I open a new file and hit the TAB button it tabs 4 spaces. This is bizarre!

I have just started using Atom, so maybe overlooking something obvious, but this is a frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1):

IT turns out there are language-specific preferences that override the general editor preferences. These are accessed via `Edit > Preferences > Packages > language-python > Settings` which is where the tab length was set to 4.